# lambda expressions that cannot be converted to expression trees

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

From C# in depth: "Not all lambda expressions can be converted to expression trees"

Is there any documentation as to exactly which lambda expressions *cannot* be converted to expression trees (ie statement is one of them)

(In case this has changed over time pls refer me to the latest .net core 3 and c# 7.3 relevant info)

Comment: can I just check: you're talking purely about *expressions*, i.e. one-liners, not "statement body" lambdas (things with `{` / `}` scopes)?

Comment: I'm asking about which lambdas I can or cannot assign to expressions that can then be translated by the compiler, I know statement is not valid and I think assignment ?

Comment: [Relevant section in the draft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#anonymous-function-conversions): the compile time conversion fails if the lambda expression "has a *block* body, contains simple or compound assignment operators, contains a dynamically bound expression, or is async." As to whether any of these have been relaxed between then and now would require someone to read patches, I guess, failing an up to date spec being available. (Which is getting a little embarrassing, actually -- C# 8 is close to release.)

Comment: Thx Jeroen  ! Can you post this as an answer ?